# Tool to put selected code in a separate function

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

Is there any tool/functionality in IntelliJ/Android Studio/... to put some selected code in a separate function (Like a function builder)?

I know it's a very lazy person question, but this tool could be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [Extract method](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/extract-method.html) refactoring. You can access it via *Refactor/Extract/Method* menu or using a keyboard shortcut:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Linux, Windows)
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (OS X)

Answer (score 3):

Select the code >> Right Click >> Refactor >> Extract >> Method :

[image]